# How to check if field is of formula type or not in dynamic apex?

Tags: apex, formula, describesobject, describefieldresult

```
public static void getFieldNames(String objName){

    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
        .get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values())
    {
        schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();
        system.debug(dfield.getname() + ': '+ dfield.getType());
    }
}
```

I have the above code where it takes the object name as the argument and prints all the fields for that object along with their data types. But I am also looking for a way to know if any of those fields are formula fields.

Looks like the `getType` method returns result of the formula field but I need to know if that field is a formula field or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the `isCalculated` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isCalculated) on `DescribeFieldResult`:

```
public static Boolean isFormula(SObjectField field)
{
    return field.getDescribe().isCalculated();
}
```